# GPG Encryption failing in SSMS Job agent and successful in SSIS

Tags: sql, encryption, ssis, gnupg

I have a encryption job set, it executes just fine in Visual studio but give the following error in SSMS job agent-->
Error retrieving emailid@domain.com via WKD:No data gpg
skipped: No Data

Using SQL 2017. I tried using CMDEXEC instead of SSIS Package in job settings but it doesn't solve the problem

Arguments:

```
--quiet --yes --trust-model always --passphrase mypassphrase --recipient XXX@XXX.com  --trust-model always --output D:\Folder\File.csv.gpg --encrypt D:\Folder\file.csv
```

[image: Error in SSMS Job]

[image: Arguments in SSIS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was executing job from the proxy account and apparently proxy and own account is different when it comes to gpg key import. Meaning- I had imported keys using gpg/Kleopatra in my desktop using my windows credentials and was calling the job with my proxy account from job agent. Hence the proxy account was not able to access the keys. This is what solved my problem- https://superuser.com/questions/1176705/windows-account-cant-see-gpg-key#new-answer

Comment: work-around for copying GPG keys between windows accounts: look in %AppData%\Roaming\GnuPg for each user and just copy the contents from the account that has the keys working properly to the account that needs to have the keys imported.